# Spring Integration Design - processing lines in a file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to understand the "best" way to accomplish this goal:

Using FileReadingMessageSource as the source
for each line in the file (using FileSplitter)
augment the row of data and send a REST request to another server and wait for a response.

Now sending the REST request is not a transform, I don't think it is an adapter, not a router.

What is it?  what is the right way to design this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but I'll try my best.

To call REST service you should use `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`, which essentially is a `gateway` EI pattern implementation. But from the application perspective it is a `service` any way. So, to handle message to the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` you should use `@ServiceActivator`. That is a term to proceed.